# Copy filtered rows from file to open workbook

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to open a currently closed workbook, filter column A based on Sel_RC (A2 is the header), copy only the visible rows and paste into ThisWorkbook, sheet "LRD".

```
Sub Get_RC_Data()

Dim wbSource As Workbook, wbDest As Workbook
Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsDest As Worksheet
Dim rngSource As Range, rngDest As Range
Dim Sel_RC As Range

Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
Set wsDest = wbDest.Worksheets("LRD")
Set rngDest = wsDest.Range("A:CY")

Set Sel_RC = wbDest.Worksheets("Summary").Range("B2")

Set wbSource = Workbooks.Open("G:\Folder\File.xlsm")
Set wsSource = wbSource.Worksheets("data")
wsSource.Range("A2").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sel_RC
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("A2:CY2"), 
wsSource.Range("A2:CY2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

rngDest.Value = rngSource.Value

wbSource.Close (False)

End Sub
```

Everything works fine except for the line:

```
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("A2:CY2"), wsSource.Range("A2:CY2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

The problem I'm having is I can't get the source range to select **only** the visible filtered rows. I've tried a combination of the above - the current one copies row 2 into every row of the destination sheet. I've also had similar semi success with:

```
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range("A:CY")
```

which copied and pasted correctly but ignored the filter (i.e. just copied all rows from the source).

Thanks.

Comment: You have to iterate over the areas in rngSource. rngDest.Value = rngSource.Value doesn't work for composite ranges.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the range to the top-left and bottom-right cells only, then Copy the visible cells:

```
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("A2"), 
    wsSource.Range("CY2").End(xlDown)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

rngSource.Copy

wsDest.Activate
rngDest.Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

OR

```
Set rngSource = wsSource.Range(wsSource.Range("A2"), 
    wsSource.Range("CY2").End(xlDown))

rngSource.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy

wsDest.Activate
rngDest.Cells(1, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```

Comment: Thanks Andy, this makes sense. However, it's falling down on the rngDest(1,1).Select line, saying "Select method of Range class failed". Any ideas?

Comment: I've tried both methods and get the same error. It also seems to be copying all the rows from the source bar the last 2? Thanks again for the help by the way

Comment: Is CY2 part of the filtered range? Does this column contain some blank cells, causing `End()` to fail? Step through the code and check the ranges.

Comment: Ah of course, moved the 'End()' to resolve potential blanks in CY (none in A). Still getting the error on the 'rngDest.Cells(1,1).Select'  line though.

Comment: You might need `wsDest.Activate` before `rngDest.Cells(1, 1).Select`. I've added this statement. Or even activate the workbook.